# req.session doesn't reflect updated flash messages from the database 

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, session, passport.js

I am using express-session, express-flash, and Passport.js for my authentication system. I want to send a flash message to the client when the authentication fails, but it seems that there is a discrepancy between the flash message in req.session and the actual session in the database.

During my initial login attempt (with wrong email), I was getting the correct req.session as it's the data reflected from the session store.

**Initial login / req.session**

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'none'
  },
  flash: { error: [ 'Invalid email' ] }
}
```

**Initial login / session store**

```
+----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| session_id                       | expires    | data                                                                                                                                             |
+----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| pBoyFLVb0Vj3vya929IYFURDO9Sb7rmI | 1690298184 | {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"secure":true,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/","sameSite":"none"},"flash":{"error":["Invalid email"]}} |
+----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After I tried to log in AGAIN with **correct email and incorrect password**, req.session is not updated and return the following

**Second login / req.session**

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'none'
  },
  flash: { error: [ 'Invalid email' ] }
}
```

**Second login / session store**

```
+----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| session_id                       | expires    | data                                                                                                                                             |
+----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| pBoyFLVb0Vj3vya929IYFURDO9Sb7rmI | 1690298184 | {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"secure":true,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/","sameSite":"none"},"flash":{"error":["Invalid email","Incorrect password"]}} |
+----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, the most recent flash message is in the session store but not in req.session. On my 3rd attempt (with either wrong username or password), the req.session will then show the previous update which doesn't reflect the current data in session store.

```
"error":["Invalid email","Incorrect password"]
```

It's like it's 1 step behind the session store. I should have 3 error on my third failed attempt.

**index.ts**

```
AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(async () => {
    console.log('initialized database!');
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.ORIGIN || 'http://127.0.0.1:5173',
    credentials: true,
  })
);

const storeOptions = {
  ...
};

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.MY_SESSION_SECRET,
    store: new MySQLStore(storeOptions),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
    },
  })
);

app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const userRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(User);
setPassport(
  passport,
  async function (email) {
    const user = await userRepository.findOneBy({ email: email });
    return user;
  },
  async function (id) {
    const user = await userRepository.findOneBy({ user_id: id });
    return user;
  }
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello API');
});

app.use('/api/users', userRouter);
app.use('/api/routines', isAuth, routineRouter);
app.use('/api/workouts', isAuth, workoutRouter);
..
```

**passport-config.ts (setPassport)**

```
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from 'passport-local';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

function setPassport(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  async function authUser(email, password, done) {
    const user = await getUserByEmail(email);
    try {
      if (user == null) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid email' });
      }
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect Password' });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return done(error);
    }
  }

  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: 'email',
      },
      authUser
    )
  );
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    return done(null, user.user_id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    const user = await getUserById(id);
    return done(null, user);
  });
}

export default setPassport;
```

**userRoutes.ts**

```
const userRouter = express.Router();
const userRepo = AppDataSource.getRepository(User);

interface UserDataType extends Request {
  user: {
    username: string;
    user_id: number;
    email: string;
  };
}

declare module 'express-session' {
  interface SessionData {
    flash: {
      error: string[];
    };
  }
}

userRouter.post(
  '/signin',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/api/users',
    failureRedirect: '/api/users/failure',
    failureFlash: true,
  })
);


userRouter.get('/failure', async (req, res) => {
  **console.log(req.session);**
  let message = 'should be latest message from flash.error';
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    process.env.ORIGIN || 'http://127.0.0.1:5173'
  );
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  return res.status(403).send(message);
});

userRouter.get('/', isAuth, (req: UserDataType, res: Response) => {
  const { username, user_id, email } = req.user;
  try {
    res.status(200).send({ username, user_id, email });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send('Interal server error');
  }
});
```

From what I understand is, when the login fails, Passport.js should save flash message to session store and req.session before redirects to failureRedirect, therefore, there should be no difference between req.session and session data in session storage. Can anyone please help me out? I've been stuck for like 2 days